# Why does my Navigation Bar disappear in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

I have a navigation bar on my Table View Controller. When I run the simulator and navigate from the menu via UIButton, the navigation bar appears on the controller. However when I navigate to another page using a navigation bar, then return to the Table View, the navigation bar disappears.

I provided a screen shot of my main storyboard.

[The main storyboard from my Xcode project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYUKZ.png)

Comment: you should create your segue to the navigation Controller, not to the tablet, that way you will have your bar.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Comment: Please mark my answer as correct, Glad it help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create your segue to the navigation Controller, not to the tablet, that way, you will have your bar.